# Bluetooth Pairing for headless device

Tags: java, android, ios, bluetooth

I just started android programming recently.

I've been trying to write a code for a headless device.

I can enable the bluetooth functions without user interaction (as it's a headless device). However, I'm now stuck at the bluetooth pairing function. So far, I still need to pair the devices through user interaction (pressing the pair button as it has a unique randomly generated passkey).

I've tried the BluetoothDevice.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord method and matching BluetoothAdapter.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord method but I still can't seem to be getting it right.

> ```
> try
>     {
>         tmp = MyBluetoothDevice.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
>     }
>     catch (IOException e) { }
>     MyBluetoothSocket=tmp;
>
>
>
> try
>         {
>             // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
>             // until it succeeds or throws an exception
>             MyBluetoothSocket.connect();
>         }
>         catch (IOException e)
>         {
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         }
> ```

I may be missing some code but I've been stuck here for days. Does anyone have any idea how to go around it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: how you would be showing the pairing code on a headless device?

Comment: that's what I'm trying to figure out, atm I'm using the logcat to view as my "ui" substitute. but i can't seem to get the pairing code. any ideas?

Comment: keep a specific pre-defined pairing code for the device

Comment: I can't pre-define the pairing code as it is generated by the phone